# Validate search form without model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this form in rails, in my view new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for( @rent , html: { class: 'form-horizontal' }) do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="" class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 control-label">year:</label>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
      <%= f.text_field :year, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
      <%= f.submit 'Buscar', :class =>"btn btn-sm btn-info btn-flat" %>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: @rent %>
```

In my controller I have this

```
class RentsController < ApplicationController
    def new
      @rent = RentSearch.new
    end

    private
      def search_params
        params.require(:year).permit(:year)
      end
end
```

In my model, had this code:

```
class RentSearch
    include ActiveModel::Validations
    include ActiveModel::Conversion
    extend ActiveModel::Naming

    attr_accessor :year

    validates :year, presence: true
    validates :year, length: { is: 4 }
end
```

With this code I get this error

> undefined method `persisted?' for #

But I made some modifications and not show error, but when submit not display any error and form is empty, I don't know how can solve this.

What is the best way to create a form in rails without model access to database and passing all validations to the controller and verify.

Comment: Sorry i'm new, but your request is done

Answer (score 0):

---

**MY SOLUTION**

Thanks to @Зелёный for help.

route.rb

```
resources :rents, only: [:index, :new, :create]
```

rent.rb - model

```
class Rent
  # Validations
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  extend ActiveModel::Naming

  attr_accessor :year

  validates :year, presence: true
  validates :year, length: { is: 4 }

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    attributes.each do |name, value|
      send("#{name}=", value)
    end
  end

  def persisted?
    false # which means this object persisted in the database.
  end
end
```

rents_controller.rb

```
class RentsController < ApplicationController

    def index
      @params = params
    end

    def new
      @rent = Rent.new
    end

    def create
      @rent = Rent.new( params['/rents'] )
      if @rent.valid?
        redirect_to tg_rents_path( year: params['/rents']['year'] )
      else
        render :action => 'new'
      end
    end

end
```

new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for( tg_rents_path , url: {action: "create"}, html: { class: 'form-horizontal' }) do |f| %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="" class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 control-label">year:</label>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
        <%= f.text_field :year, class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
        <%= f.submit 'Search', :class =>"btn btn-sm btn-info btn-flat" %>
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
<% end %>

<%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: @rent %>
```

Thanks to all!!